# Как загрузить данные из текстового документа по выбранному в ListBox имени?

Tags: c++builder, c++

В данный момент загрузка происходит с помощью такого кода:

```
ListBox2->ItemIndex = 0;

if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Васин А.А."))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/vasin.txt");
}
if (ListBox2->Items->Strings[ListBox2->ItemIndex] == AnsiString("Иванов С.И."))
{
Memo3->Lines->Clear();
Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/ivanov.txt");
}
```

И так далее...

Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на какого-либо студента в ListBox считывалось его имя и загружало в Memo сведения по нему. Помогите, плз. )

Скриншот программы для наглядности:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public: void listBox::onClick(...) {
    Memo3->Lines->Clear();
    Memo3->Lines->LoadFromFile("texts/" + string(listBox2->seletedIndex)));    
}
```

Код неточен, но принцип такой:
 - навесить обработчик события click на ваш listBox;
 - в этом обработчике считывать индекс или значение выбранного элемента;
 - по полученным данным определить с какого файла считать (это уже придумайте сами).